# Why are my Pokémon dozing off?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

When I do battle, sometimes I’ll get a message that says:

> [Pokémon] is dozing off... It must be sleepy.

This has happened to three of my Pokémon so far. I haven’t noticed any effect of it yet (positive or negative), but I’m still curious why it’s happening. The opposing Pokémon haven’t used Yawn or any other sleep-inducing move, hence why I’m confused.

Why is it happening?

Comment: I assume you've not been hit with [Yawn](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Yawn_(move))?

Comment: The opposing Pokémon so far haven’t used the move yet, so no. I’ve experienced Yawn before in earlier games, so I’d have noticed if they’d used it. That’s the part that confuses me.

Comment: Now I’m getting “[Pokémon] seems worried it’s not able to do battle well” after getting hit by Smack Down. Not sure if it’s related, though, but these messages are starting to get worrisome.

Comment: What level are your pokemon? Maybe they are higher level than your gym badge allows.

Comment: Level 30, and I’ve already got the second badge. According to my trainer card, I should be able to command Pokémon up to level 40.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This has to do with the Pokémon’s [Affection](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Affection). While the source has not updated to reflect Sword/Shield yet, this dialog also appears in Sun and Moon in the same scenarios.

The dialog you see is just alternate text when your Pokémon is thrown in at the beginning of the battle, and it is varies based on the Pokémon’s affection. Based on the information in your question (and comments), the affection level is 2 out of 5.

In Sword/Shield, you can check your Pokémon’s affection by playing with them in the camp. Simply call your Pokémon over and talk to them. When you talk to them, the number of hearts that are shown above their head indicates the affection level.

According to Bulbapedia, the following are benefits your Pokémon will get based on it's affection level

> - At affection level 2 and higher, a Pokémon will gain 1.2 times the normal experience from battles.
> - At affection level 3 and higher, a Pokémon may endure attacks that could otherwise make it faint and survive with 1 HP (including confusion damage). This can activate multiple times per turn.
> - At affection level 4 and higher, a Pokémon can sometimes:
>
>   - Avoid attacks, even when they have 100% accuracy. This can activate multiple times per turn.
>   - Shake off status conditions at the end of the turn.
> - At affection level 5 and higher, a Pokémon's chance of scoring a critical hit is doubled.

Answer (score -2):

I feel like the your pokemon is dozing off would have something to do with the day and night cycle like your pokemon being afraid it wont battle well has to do something with type matchups after your pokemon gets to a certain level of affection. Like last night my level 86 umbreon(dark) was up against a level 60 kommo-oo (dragon/fighting) because dark is weak to fighting umbreon was afraid that it would not be able to fight.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to the site.  That's a good thought, but unfortunately it's incorrect; see the accepted answer (above yours) for the correct explanation.  Thanks for posting!